# How do I trigger a checkbox with Armature? Is there a way?

Tags: armature, smoke-simulation

I have a cube, I want this cube to generate smoke at a certain key frame, but I want an armature to trigger it. The problem is blender keeps crashing when I render so there is something I'm doing wrong.

[image]

Is there a way I can use Custom Properties of a bone to turn smoke on and off?  I've attached my blender file with a driver that triggers this.

I think I'm doing this all wrong, because this is a boolean value and I'm using ints, but how are checkboxes supposed to be triggered?  I don't want to do it via keyframe because it creates it's own action.  I want this smoke to be in the same armature as my character.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MuAOXRRb1IH_1LDxSNncy9fkJeH4jbg2/view?usp=drive_link

Thank you.